# How to implement git hook for Android repo tool

Tags: python, android, git, repo

My team is using [android repo](https://source.android.com/setup/develop/repo) for the project. I've been facing and issue where I've wanted to write my hook for the `repo` following the documentation, however the doc's of `repo` seems to allow only one [pre-upload](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/HEAD/docs/repo-hooks.md) hook - and I'm in need of implementing `pre-commit` and cant get it to work.

Does anyone ever tried implementing [git-hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/uz/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) for repo and have any tutorials/tips/tricks/guildlines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1, config system-wide or global `core.hooksPath`.

```
git config --system core.hooksPath /path/to/githooks
```

The hooks under `/path/to/githooks` will be provoked. If you are using Gerrit and `Change-Id` is required, copy the `commit-msg` to the path too.

Solution 2, if you use your own `repo` repository instead of Google's, you can add and commit the hook scripts under `repo/hooks` so that the repos created by `repo sync` will create soft links to `.repo/repo/hooks/*`. To use your own `repo` repository, you can change the value of `REPO_URL` in the `repo` script used to run `repo init`. The value is the url of your own `repo` repository.

Comment: Thank you for the ideas! I didn't knew the server side has an impact as well ( Gerrit/Gitlab/Bitbucket/ect... )

I think that:
**Solution 1** is messing up the repositories that use different language or follow different policies regarding code quality, formatting, etc... :(

**Solution 2** unfortunately I'm useing Google's `repo` and it would require a manual action to make a change befor `repo sync` ( however you gave me an idea that maybe there could be some init script for the project put in place here )

Comment: @Verthais it's more flexible to maintain and use a fork of Google's `repo` repository. Deliver the modified `repo` script (used for `repo init`) to all the team members and ask them to replace the one in `PATH`, once for all. They don't have to do any other changes. Besides, you can customize the `repo` tool for more needs.